# resolving a javascript and database table logic situation

Tags: javascript, mysql

When I query a database table, I get back values "yes" or "no" for records that represent whether an item is present or not (the item is the column name).  I want to create a string that represents the products that are available by name (rather than what I am doing now "kitchen table =" + kitchenTable;

I am thinking this can be solved (poorly) by a series of if statements setting variables to either the product name or to "" and then include all variables in the string

```
var kt; 
if (kitchenTable == yes) kt = "kitchen table"; 
else kt = ""; 
if (kitchenCabinet == yes) kc = "kitchen cabinet";
else ka = "";

output = kt + ', ' + kc;
```

There are about 50 items that can be presented to the user, is there a more efficient way of accomplishing this task??  One option is to change how values are entered into the datbase table such that instead of yes, its the item name but this seems like a poorer way to resolve the issue

Comment: I want to clarify; for each item there is a column? So, there are about 50 columns, correct? And the rows are whatever contains the items, maybe a house number/name or room with some sort of unique identifier?

Comment: How does the answer I wrote work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you don't give all the details about how do you make query so that is an imaginary mockup of a function simulating query

```
var available = [];

var result = query("kitchen table");
result === "yes" && ( available.push("kitchen table") );
```

......

```
var output = available.join();
```

Comment: sorry, currently all the data is passed from ajax to javascript, once i get this working I will try to accomplish this task on the ajax side...but for now I want to go about it the easy route.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is actually built into javascript itself.

I would say using an object literal will really simply your life in this situation by organizing your code and turning it into a more readable format.

I would also recommend turning your server data into true and false as this is a standardized way to communicated a Boolean and allows for the method below to work as it does:

```
// From server response
var results = {
                    kitchenCabinet: true,
                    kitchenTable: true
}

// Use this for your storage of all related items
var kitchenProps = { 
                  kitchenCabinet: 'kitchen cabinet',
                  kitchenTable: 'kitchen table'
 }

// Reuse this function for each time your need a new category (masterBathroomProps...)
function getItemDataIfExists(results, hashTable){
    'use strict';

    var output = 'Your total is: '; 

    for (var item in results) {
        if (!results.hasOwnProperty(item)) return;
        if (results[item]) output += 'A '+hashTable[item]+' ';
    }

    return output;
}


getItemDataIfExists(results, kitchenProps);
```

Explanation:

You loop through a result set of an object containing keys names and true false values. In the loop, if the keyname's value is  true, then use that keyname to access the properties (in this case a string of your choice. The "key" here is that the key names in each object must line up.

Here is a live demo:

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/JXXbYz?editors=0010